# Dynamic Custom Permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I have a scenario in which the intention is to make custom permalink that can be changed dynamically, for example:

- If a country information is showing up then the URL should be `http://example.com/country-information`
- If the city information of that specific country is showing up then the URL should be like `http://example.com/country/city-information`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are cities and countries custom post types?

Comment: Yeah! They were meant to be custom post types but i had managed to do in another way by doing some URL rewriting.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, so other readers can learn something.

Comment: Please share your solution Adil - I am also trying to do this and am using rewrite but I cant see how to get a particular template to show based on http://example.com/england-information http://example.com/india-information

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "changed dynamically", but the simplest way to achieve what you're talking about is to use pages (or a hierarchical custom post type), and make the "city-information" pages into children of the "country-information" page they are associated with. Then set permalinks to "Post Name", and you'll get the urls you're looking for.

Comment: By involving some jQuery to avoid "page refresh" every time. Sorry! I was away but I was able to achieve that back then with URL Rewriting, and got that hierarchical order you have said! Thanks for the help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `add_rewrite_rule()`? For example:

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'country-information/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?country-information=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );
```

After adding the new rule, you have to flush the permalink, Admin > Permalinks > Save

Then add a new query var via `add_filter`, needed to allow custom rewrite rules using your own arguments to work, or any other custom query variables you want to be publicly available.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'country-information';
    return $query_vars;
} );
```

You can also use a custom particular template for that permalink using `template_include` hook.

```
function conutry_information_template( $template ) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'country-information' ) === false || get_query_var( 'country-information' ) == '' ) {
        return $template;
    }
 
    return get_template_directory() . '/country-information.php';
}
add_action( 'template_include', 'conutry_information_template' );
```